# VS 2013 “DEBUG” –> “Other Debug Targets” missing

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, remote-debugging

I found multiple tutorials on the net that asked me to open VisualStudio 2013 Update 2 and there, select "Other Debug Targets" from the DEBUG menu. ([example tutorial](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davrous/archive/2014/07/21/how-to-remotely-debug-and-profile-the-performance-of-your-html5-websites-amp-apps-on-windows-phone.aspx))

In the screenshots provided there, said menu item is located below "Attach to process", but above "Performance and Diagnostics".

In my copy of VisualStudio 2013, which is 12.0.21005.1 REL, I don't find that menu item. In fact, a different item shows up at that position: "Debug installed app package...", which should be one sub-item of the item I don't find.

The shortcut named in the tutorial, Ctrl+Shift+P, doesn't work either.

Which fixpack or feature will I have to install to finally be able to debug WindowsPhone IE?

Comment: 12.0.21005.1 REL means your running the RTM version of 2013, *not* Update 2 (or later). Update 2 is 12.0.30324.0 and Update 4 is 12.0.31101.0

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Wouldn't Update 2 be applied automatically by Windows Update? Because it isn't, as far as I can tell. I am just now looking into not-yet-installed Windows Updates, but as far as I can see, VS 2013 Update 2 is not in the list.

Comment: No, Visual Studio updates aren't applied via Windows Update. They're more akin to Service Packs. Here's [update 4](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=44921).